How to handle viewmodel ui states in composable
I was wondering what is correct approach to handle the ui state with compose
would it be better in terms of performance to have multiple state flows or just one state flow for whole UI.
Example for one one stateflow
:
SomeViewModel
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<Settings?>(null)
    override val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    private fun loadSettings() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val loadedProfile = api.getProfile()
            _uiState.emit(loadedProfile.settings)
        }
    }

and then in Composable just do something like this
 val uiState = SomeViewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(null)
and whenever we update a setting then we would just emit new uiState that would update whole uiState object
Another approach i have in mind is just have separate state for every setting
    private val _uiStateSetting1 = MutableStateFlow<int?>(null)
    override val uiStateSetting1= _uiState.asStateFlow()
    private val _uiStateSetting2 = MutableStateFlow<bool>(false)
    override val uiStateSetting2= _uiState.asStateFlow()


then in Composable function we could do it like this
 val uiState1 = SomeViewModel.uiStateSetting1.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(null) val uiState2 = SomeViewModel.uiStateSetting2.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(false)
and emit new state for every setting separately

You should group similar values in a data class, like you do with your Settings (just make sure all the properties are declared with val, making the data class immutable). This reduces the overhead for having multiple flows and reduces boilerplate code in the view model and your composables.
You probably shouldn't mix vastly different kinds of values in a single flow, especially when they are not related to each other. This makes it more clear what the responsibility of each flow is. Also you might want to extract values into a separate flow when they are updated very frequently to reduce unnecessary recompositions in unrelated parts of your UI.

Thanks, for your reply, i already have huge  data class for my Settings so i was mainly thinking that alternative to boilerplate would be need to collect state flow in every custom composable function i create
